# how to calculate $ \bmod 2 \pi$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, pi

Context: I wanted to calculate $ \sin( \frac{ \pi (n!)^2}{k})$  through calculating $\frac{ \pi (n!)^2}{k} \bmod 2\pi$

(n!)^2 is too big so I wondered if it was possible to take $\bmod 2 \pi$ at every multiplication.
using the fact, that $ (a \bmod c) * (b \bmod c) = ((a * b) \bmod c) $ but that doesn't work in this case
since for example:
$ a = (7  \bmod 2\pi) \approx 0.716815 $

$ b = (8 \bmod 2\pi) \approx 1.71681$

$ a * b \approx 1.23064$ but
$(8 * 7 \bmod 2  \pi) \approx 5.73452$

I also don't understand, what $\frac{1}{k} \bmod 2\pi $ means.

Comment: Try using that $$\frac{\pi(n!)^2}{k}\pmod{2\pi}=\pi\bigg(\frac{(n!)^2}{k}\pmod2\bigg)$$

Comment: it's then plugged into sin(x). so $ \sin( \frac{ \pi * (n!)^2}{k}) $

Comment: @Rhys Hughes  I don't understand how I would use that, since (n!) is 0 mod 2 for n >= 2

Comment: If $k\le n$, then $\frac{(n!)^2}{k}$ is also $0\bmod 2$. So $\frac{\pi(n!)^2}{k}\bmod 2\pi$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be pitched at the right level.

The reason multiplication goes wrong is that you are really only able to reduce addition modulo $2\pi$ by working with the additive group $\mathbb R/2\pi \mathbb Z$. The reason multiplication will not work boils down to the fact that $2\pi \mathbb Z$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb R$.

To see this more concretely, take $a + 2\pi m$ and $b + 2\pi n$. Their product is
$$ab + 2\pi mb + 2\pi an + (2\pi)^2 mn$$
We would really like to be able to work modulo $2\pi$ to remove all the multiples of $2\pi$, but the problem is that we only allow ourselves to treat *integer* multiples of $2\pi$ as $0$, but in general none of the terms on the right will be integer multiples of $2\pi$.

In your case, you are able to take $a,b$ to be integers, but there is no way to "fix" the $(2\pi)^2 mn$ in this situation, except if $m$ or $n$ is zero (clearly there's no problem in that situation - for instance if $m=0$ then the product is $ab + 2\pi an$ which does equal $ab$ mod $2\pi$ if $a$ is an integer).